# Wordpress image rendering problem on iPhone 6 / iPhone6 Plus

Tags: ios, wordpress, image-rendering

We have a page that contains 20 .svg images. Page renders completely fine on first load for all of the devices that we tested but specifically for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus once we scrolled the page to bottom or to top a little fast images gets disappeared and it takes time to re-render it I have tried couple different solutions but none of them seem to work. I would really appreciate some help.

The page that I have been facing problem with : https://transform.makeen.io/forms

Video from an iPhone 6 :

https://youtu.be/XPQza2fDzjs

Video from an iPhone 8 :

https://youtu.be/OKbTUORQAG4

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be related `loading="lazy"`. Since Wordpress `5.5` by default `loading="lazy"` is applied to images as it became a native browser behaviour.

- Source @ [//make.wordpress.org/core/.../lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/14/lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/#:%7E:text=In%20WordPress%205.5%2C%20images%20will,web%20standard%20earlier%20in%202020.)

We can disable this native behaviour by using this filter `wp_lazy_loading_enabled` hook filter in your `function.php`.

```
add_filter( 'wp_lazy_loading_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

As per the [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/loading-lazy-attr) the support for attribut `loading="lazy"` is still has a global of only `72.72%`.

| IE | Edge | Firefox | Chrome | Safari | IOS Safari |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Not Supported | Supported | Partial Support | Supported | Not Supported but can be enabled | Not Supported but can be enabled |

As you can see IOS doesn't support it by default which may cause some loading problem.

If you move forward with this I would suggest switching back to an old-school lazy loading method or perhaps a page transition loader.

---

### Learn more

- [Browser-level image lazy-loading for the web](https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/)
- [Lazy loading MDN Web DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case if it was related to Safari it wouldn't render the images on iPhone 8 too. To make sure I apply the suggested solution but still it takes too much time to render it on iPhone 6. Thank you anyways :)